# How to use Random Variables in JMS Selector with JMeter JMS Subscriber

Tags: jms, jmeter, activemq-classic

Has any one succeeded in using JMeter Random variable in JMS Selector with JMeter JMS Subscriber for ActiveMQ.

So far I tried to use like below for Random variables but no luck.

```
JMSCorrelationID ='${msgCorrelation_ID}'
```

Above selector is working if msgCorrelation_ID is defined as UDV but I need to use Random values per threads.

Answer (score 2):

How do you set your `msgCorrelation_ID`? What value does [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) report?

As a solution I can suggest straightforward way of explicit generation of msgCorrelation_ID variable.

Add a [Beanshell Pre Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor) to your request configured as follows:

**Parameters:** `${__RandomString(10,abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789,)}`

**Script:** `vars.put("msgCorrelation_ID", Parameters);`

This will populate `msgCorrelation_ID` variable with random alphanumeric string of 10 characters. You will be able to refer to it where required as ${msgCorrelation_ID} or ${__V(msgCorrelation_ID)}

References:

- [__randomString() function documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString)
- [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide on Beanshell scripting for Apache JMeter

Answer (score 1):

This is because UDV are initialized at test plan startup. Since you have created your variable in Processor, you need to check `Setup: Each sample` on JMS Subscriber screen, so connection is initialized after `${msgCorrelation_ID}` initialization.

[image: Dynamic JMeter JMSSelector]

[image: Dynamic JMeter JMSSelector each sample]